# The parameter is incorrect while finding video capture sources in Directshow

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

By using Directshow.NET I have developed an `C#` application everything is fine but on some machines I am unable to find video capture sources (camera) by line of using code `DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice)`. This line of code generating Exception `The parameter is incorrect.`. I have checked with GraphStudio also but no camera is listed under `Video capture sources` but I can see the attached camera in `Device Manager`.

While checking with Directshow Filter Manager I get following error:

> The parameter is incorrect.
>
> Scope:[CDENum.CreateClassEnumerator({860BB310-5D01-11d0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86})].

What is the possible cause of this, where camera is found under Device Manager but not by Directshow? and How I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There might be certain problem with the driver of the camera (WDM or user mode driver), which prevents form normal device enumeration with DirectShow. Or there is a chance that there is another faulty device/camera that triggers an unexpected problem on enumeration. Enumeration itself is not expected to fail this way (it is [expected to return `S_FALSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406744) when no devices are found in first place), so it is likely that you need to identify faulty component installed in this particular system, and fix it to restore class enumerator operation. The first thing to do is to reinstall the drivers/software for the video device in question.

Comment: I have reinstalled graphics drivers and camera drivers also but still issue is not solved but interesting is if we unplug the camera then also exception is occurring when we check for count of camera's plugged in into the system. That means this exception is occurring irrespective of camera is attached to system or not.

Comment: I guess only last option is remaining "format the OS", is it? :(

Comment: It's well known when it works as expected. When it's broken - it could have been broken in many ways. Presumably there should be certain remains of a video capture device, which are picked up by enumerator but break it so that the failure is forwarded to your application. Even though it could possibly be fixed, I am afraid there are no step-by-step instructions on what to do exactly.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the info. I ll try.